# What's an "ignorable character in a Java identifier"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I stumbled across this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isIdentifierIgnorable-char-) and wondered what that was all about. Apparently you can have certain control characters inside identifiers and they are ignored:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int dummy = 123;
    System.out.println(d​ummy); // Has U+200B after the `d` before the `u`
}
```

I couldn't find anything about this in the JLS. IntelliJ IDEA gives an error in the editor saying "dummy" is an undeclared identifier (but nevertheless it compiles and runs). I guess that's an error in IntelliJ? What purpose do these "ignoreable characters" serve?

(Note: StackOverflow seems to remove my control characters from the question)

Comment: No warnings or errors here...

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Try adding ASCII 1 inside  one of the occurrences of `dummy`

Comment: The JLS just delegates to the documentation for `isJavaIdentifierStart` and `isJavaIdentifierPart`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

Comment: By the way, you don't have to work hard to add such a character to your source. You can use the `\u0001` format. Java compilers process these escapes before they parse the text file itself. So `dum\u0001my` is supposed to be `dummy` with that character between the two `m`s.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Doh! And I *knew* that...

Comment: Answer might be hiding inside http://unicode.org/reports/tr31/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6214519) for this contradiction.

In summary, these characters are indeed ignored for identifier name matching by the compiler but JLS doesn't mention this. Instead [JLS says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> Two identifiers are the same only if they are identical, that is, have
>   the same Unicode character for each letter or digit.

Also

> A "Java letter-or-digit" is a character for which the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int) returns true

The contradiction is obvious as:

```
Character.isJavaIdentifierPart('\u0001')  -> true, so used to compare identifier names
Character.isIdentifierIgnorable('\u0001') -> true, should be ignored actually
```

I speculate that Intellij IDEA follows the JLS or they are simply unaware of ignorable characters. I don't see a bug report for this [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=isIdentifierIgnorable).

As to what is the purpose of these ignorables, unicode specifies some [Layout and Format Control Characters](http://unicode.org/reports/tr31/#Layout_and_Format_Control_Characters). It is suggested that these characters should be ignored in identifier names as

> the effects they represent are stylistic or otherwise out of scope for
>   identifiers, and second because the characters themselves often have
>   no visible display

Apparently the purpose of `isIdentifierIgnorable` is to identify characters of this category. For instance it's mentioned in the [isIdentifierIgnorable documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isIdentifierIgnorable-char-) that it returns `true` for *characters that have the FORMAT general category value* which are characters with unicode *General_Category value of Cf* which are included in the *Layout and Format Control Characters*

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question that was asked: *"What purpose do these "ignoreable characters" serve?"*

Comment: Actually, I see no contradiction. The identifiers `dummy` and `dum\u0001my` are *identical in each letter or digit*. They are not identical in the ignorable character, but that one is not a letter or a digit.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: `_` isn't a letter or digit either, but it's significant in identifiers. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Read that JLS entry again... the definition of a "letter" is _a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` returns true_, and that includes underscores, but not ignorable characters...

Comment: @RealSkeptic Well then you're back around to the ignorable characters being a letter or digit, since they are included in `isJavaIdentifierPart`.

Comment: @Radiodef Note that being "letter-or-digit" and not being a "letter" does not imply being a "digit". The name the group was given is a mere identifier, not a logical value. The JLS may be missing a clear definition of the term "Java Digit". But the fact that the definition is missing does not imply that it includes the ignorable characters.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: That spec section uses `"Java letter"` and `"Java letter-or-digit"` when referring to those definitions (complete with the quotes). The quoted text does not, it just says "letter or digit" in the normal way. Also note that the linked section does have a definition of "Java digit": *"The "Java digits" include the ASCII digits 0-9 (\u0030-\u0039)."* (unless you're going to argue that there's an unspoken "but not limited to" after "include"). And yes, we're all nitpicking like crazy. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah. As I said, a definition of digit is missing, but "not limited to" is most certainly there as there is also a line that says "letters and digits can be drawn from the entire unicode range". Anyway, I'd sum up in saying that there is no contradiction but more clarification is needed.

Comment: @manos You claim that `isJavaIdentifierPart` is "used to compare identifier names", but that is simply not true. It is simply used to identify which characters are *legal* in an identifier, not to compare.

Comment: @RealSkeptic read the first 2 quotes in my answer from JLS. `isJavaIdentifierPart` returns true for *java letters or digits*. And then 2 identifiers names are the same if they have the same *java letters or digits*.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis No, you got it in reverse. The definition of the syntactic identifier "JLOD" (which should *not* be interpreted in any other way than what the definition says, hence I shortened it) is "whatever `isJavaIdentifierPart` returns. This definition does *not* apply to which characters are compared. Those are "letters" (a different syntactic identifier) and "digits" (yet another one). The JLOD identifier is no where mentioned in the definition of which characters should be considered when comparing.

Comment: You claim that the JLS uses the terms *Java letter or digit* and *letter or digit* for different things in the same paragraph. I disagree but that's not the point: JLS doesn't say that the *letter or digit* set of chars, that it says are used for comparison, excludes chars that are *ignorable* (per isIdentifierIgnorable). That's the contradiction.